# Angular.js Application code not working on chrome - Error "Failed to execute 'replaceState'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

Made a simple inventory application in Angular.js. Everything works fine with Firefox, Opera, IE, but not in Chrome.

> Error: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file:///C:/Users/Digital%20Jalebi%20-%20uno/Desktop/ANGULAR/index.html#/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null'.
>
> Issue at angular.js:9199

```
 if (logFn.apply) {
    return function() {
      var args = [];
      forEach(arguments, function(arg) {
        args.push(formatError(arg));
      });
      return logFn./*error*/apply(console, args);/*here*/
    };
  }
```

Read somewhere on Stack Overflow:

> Some browsers like Chrome do not allow cross-origin on file://
>
> Make sure you are running the application from a local server(like Wamp)
>
> Then it will work

Tried WAmp - no success. Let me know how to debug this.

Comment: Can you [edit] to include the error message when running on a (local) server instance?

Comment: issue is the one between * signs

Comment: The error message you gave is not one that could possibly come from any server, as it refers to an address on the local filesystem. So it's from the initial testing you mentioned. Please provide the error message from the second tests you ran, on the server instance.

Comment: your talking about running with WAMP??

Comment: Or any other server stack, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the application on the local server.